# How to capture Blob Size from Azure Blob Container in SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis

My Goal is to capture **blob details** in a database table. I don't want to download the blob to local folder and then capture the file details as I am not using that file content.

For this purpose I am creating an **SSIS** Package to capture All the blob details such as blob name, blob Size and blob last modified date etc from Azure blob container.

I am using **For Each Loop Container** to capture filename.

[image: Foreach Loop Container]

After that I am using **Script Task** to capture further details. But I am stuck here and not able to get further details of blob.

Below is the sample code I just tried but thats not helping me to go further.

Please help.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        String file_name = Dts.Variables["User::fileName"].Value.ToString();
        Dts.Variables["User::fileSize"].Value = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Dts.Variables["User::fileSize"].Value.ToString());
        Dts.Variables["User::fileDate"].Value = file_name.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToShortDateString();
        Dts.Variables["User::fileDate"].Value = file_name.CreationTime.ToShortDateString();
        long fileSize = File.Length;

        string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::fileName"].Value.ToString();
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FilePath);

        Dts.Variables["User::fileDate"].Value = file.CreationTime;
        Dts.Variables["User::fileSize"].Value = file.Length;


        //Public Sub Main()


    }
```

Comment: The way I've done this in the past is ran a scheduled Azure Automation job which checked blobs and wrote them into a database. In my opinion, using SSIS to do this is overcomplicated and kind of dated.